# Using VLOOKUP function in python with openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to automate filling in an excel file pulling data from a different excel file using the VLOOKUP function.  I am trying my script on test files first but I can't get it to run.  It has a syntax error but I am new to python so not sure if there are other issues with the script as well.[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpGU5.png)

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpxyl.utils import get_column_letter
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Original.xlsx')
wb1 = load_workbook(filename = 'New.xlsx')
ws = wb['Original']
ws1 = wb1['New']
#print(sheet_ranges['B2'].value)
for row in ws1 ['A1:A4']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = "=VLOOKUP(A{0}", 'New'!A1:B4, 2, FALSE)".format(cell.row)
```

Comment: This is not a valid string. What are you trying to assign `cell.value` with?

Comment: I am trying to pull data from the Original file into column B of the New file by searching for matches in column A of both files.

Comment: Your error message is *text*, not an image.

Comment: Yes but what is the string you are trying to create? Right now it is not valid Python. For example `'New'!A1:B4` doesn't mean nothing. Look at your question, strings are marked red so you can see the problem

Comment: I figured it out, there was a typo with an extra " in the script.  And I changed 'New' to the actual file name.  Now the script runs and saves the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have an extra `"` in the `VLOOKUP`.

```py
for row in ws1 ['A1:A4']:
    for cell in row:
        cell.value = "=VLOOKUP(A{0}, 'New'!A1:B4, 2, FALSE)".format(cell.row)
```

Comment: Yes, once I removed that I was able to run the script.  Thanks